# conditional interval in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I would like to change the interval in this SQL statement, based on a parameter in a stored procedure. I want to use three different intervals: 1 day, 8 hours, 1 hour

```
CREATE DEFINER= 'dbshizzle' PROCEDURE `getData`(in sD text(17), in sT text(8))
BEGIN
select stime, sval
from tblNumber
where sDix = 'allright'
and timestamp >= now() - interval 1 day
order by timestamp;
END
```

Should I use an IF statement with an integer parameter, or a text parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just adjusting the parameter and passing in the value as hours?

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'dbshizzle' PROCEDURE `getData`(
    in in_sD text(17),  -- should change to varchar
    in in_sT text(8),   -- should change to varchar
    in in_hours int
)
BEGIN
    select stime, sval
    from tblNumber
    where sDix = 'allright'
    and timestamp >= now() - interval in_hours hour
    order by timestamp;
END;
```